# How to count the duplicate records in MySQL while inserting data into a table

Tags: mysql

I want to count the duplicates in a sql table and populate under 'attempts' column.

To count the duplicate records, I have used the below query and it worked

```
SELECT 
    s.`accyear`,
    s.`module`,
    s.`parts`,
    s.`usercode`,
    s.`name`,
    COUNT(*) AS attempt
FROM master AS s
GROUP BY s.`accyear`,s.`module`,s.`parts`,s.`usercode`,s.`name`,
HAVING COUNT(*)>=1
```

But I need to find the duplicates while inserting them into master table and populate under 'attempts' column.

Required Output

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

master table:

[image]

******************************************************************************** Updated table structure as on 30 July 2019

---

CREATE TABLE `masterd_db`.`master_table`(
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `accyear` VARCHAR(20),
  `newassessment` VARCHAR(10),
  `period` VARCHAR(20),
  `occ` VARCHAR(10),
  `sitmodule` VARCHAR(20),
  `module` VARCHAR(20),
  `assessment` VARCHAR(80),
  `parts` VARCHAR(50),
  `sprcode` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `studentname` VARCHAR(50),
  `mark` INT,
  `candkey` VARCHAR(20),
  `timemodified` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `attempts` INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `sprcode`)
);

INSERT INTO master_table(accyear,newassessment,period,occ,sitmodule,module,assessment,parts,sprcode,studentname,mark,candkey,timemodified)
SELECT.... working query

After this all the records will be populated except "attempt" column.

I need to populate the attempts while inserting into master_table. I'll take "Required output" table as a reference. 
While inserting the first row, it will check if there are any row with year 2019, module A4DUG, parts Part 1, usercode 18900322 and name Kumar M. If it didn't find one, it will insert 1 with respect to the row under "attempts" column. In the second row, it has the same records of the first row. So it will insert 2 under "attempts" column. Similarly it should increment the attempts, if it finds more duplicate records.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.7.19

Comment: what you mean find duplicate while inserting?

Comment: I have an insert query to populate the master table. So during inserting the values, I need to check the duplicate rows on the fly and if found any update the count under 'attempt column' as shown in the "Required output" link above.

Comment: So why not `INSERT INTO Master SELECT  ...  your working query ....`

Comment: That's how I populate the Master table. INSERT INTO Master(col1,col2....) SELECT ....working query. But I need to count the duplicates and get the output as showed in "Required Output" table above

Comment: When I populate the Master table,the "attempts" column will be empty.So I'll have a table with all the records populated except for the "attempts" column. From there I have to find the duplicates. what I am thinking is that, each time it inserts a record into the Master table, it checks into the table.It needs to check year, module, parts, usercode and name. if it is a new record, under "attempts" column against that specific row, it will put value "1" and if its not then increment the value.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. On insert indicate the duplicate data elements and update counter for the relevant one. You can also implement `UNIQUE INDEX` and prevent data duplication in the table.

If you want to allow data duplication and only count attempts you can implement `AFTER INSERT` trigger

Here is the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger for `usercode`

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblmaster_after_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON tblmaster FOR EACH ROW
   SELECT @attempts := COUNT(*) FROM tblmaster WHERE usercode = NEW.usercode;
   UPDATE tblmaster SET attempts = @attempt + 1 WHERE id =  NEW.id;
```

Comment: I didn't understand "NEW.usercode and NEW.id". Could you please explain? Not only the usercode, I need to check year, module, parts, name as well.

Comment: ``NEW.usercode`` returns the new value of the data element, in this case it is ``usercode``. This ``NEW`` is only available for ``INSERT`` and ``UPDATE`` trigger. You can implement the same logic for other data elements. Do you need to indicate duplicates when all data elements are duplicated or some of them? What is the exact logic for increment ``attempts`` that you want to implement?

Comment: When I run the above trigger, I am getting this error: Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'NEW.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: When I changed "SELECT..... to  "SELECT.....INTO ...", then Trigger got created

CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger4
AFTER INSERT
   ON master_table FOR EACH ROW
   SELECT @attempts := COUNT(*) INTO at_attempts FROM master_table WHERE sprcode = NEW.sprcode;
   UPDATE master_table SET attempts = at_attempts + 1 WHERE id =  NEW.id; 
After creating trigger, I performed the INSERT query, but still, the "attempts" column is not populated